# BCC or CC in Reply - Sender Profile

Tags: marketing-cloud

How Do I add BCC or CC in Sender Profile Under Reply section?

For example currently I am using %%AgentEmail%% in Reply of Sender Profile, So I want when receiver reply the email one reply goes to Agent (which is working) and the same reply should be CC to lets say xyz@gmail.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CC and BCC options have to be enabled by SFMC Support.

Reference: [Email Messages](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_messages/)